# How to display information from uploaded file in Angular HTML

Tags: angular, api, http, post, upload

I have created an upload function in a service file in Angular that submits a post request to an API to upload a file, like so

```
onUpload() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('uploadfile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    return this.http
      .post(api_url, formData, {
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events',
        responseType: 'text',
      })
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);

      })
        
    }
```

I want to at the same time take those uploaded files and display the file names, and maybe some other information  in a list in HTML. How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When is that function getting invoked? On form submit or file upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the details of files using the `change` event.

**HTML :**

```html
<input type="file" (change)="onFilesUpload($event)">
```

**TS :**

```js
list : any[];

onFilesUpload(event){

    // Iterate over selected files
    for( let file of event.target.files ) {
      
        // Append to a list
        this.list.push({
            name : file.name,
            type : file.type
            // Other specs
        });
    }
}
```

Use the final `list` to show the details.